# Transaction is talking very long

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I sent a transaction from blockchain wallet to localbitcoins.  Keeps saying it should be thirty minutes, and that has been going on 4 and half hours!

It needs 3 confirms and has 0!

Any help advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is the receiving wallets problem. Some wallets can take dozens of confirmations, which can take up to 24 hours.

Comment: Some custodial services may require multiple confirmations, but a normal bitcoin wallet should not. In any case, OP mentioned that it is still an unconfirmed transaction.